# How to change the reference indexing to incorporate volume and number in article (Biblatex)?

Tags: biblatex

The default bibtex reference style lists the article as (e.g.):

## A. S. Arnold, J. S. Wilson, and M. G. Boshier. “A Simple Extended-Cavity Diode Laser”. Review of Scientific Instruments 69.3 (1998), pp. 1236–1239 (cit. on pp. 10).

However, for my doctoral thesis, the reference requirements are something like this

## A. S. Arnold, J. S. Wilson, and M. G. Boshier. “A Simple Extended-Cavity Diode Laser”. Review of Scientific Instruments, vol. 69, no. 3 (1998), pp. 1236–1239 (cit. on pp. 10).

Any pointers, how to implement it?

PS:

I am loading the biblatex package as:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,bibstyle=numeric,isbn=false,doi=false,hyperref=true,url=false,compress=true,backref=true,refsection=chapter,sorting=none,abbreviate=true]{biblatex}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The format of a field can be controlled by `\DeclareFieldFormat` which has an optional argument to specify the entry type.

For `article` you can use:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}
```

However getting the space between the volume and number you have to redefine `volume+number+eid`.

```
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%orig: \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
```

---

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,bibstyle=numeric,isbn=false,doi=false,hyperref=true,url=false,backref=true,sorting=none,abbreviate=true]{biblatex}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Marco, I tried replicating your approach for 'inproceedings', but it didn't worked? Can you please tell me how to incorporate a comma in between the Journal name and the volume?

Comment: @user1668943: To get a comman+space you have to redefine the complete bibliography driver. I think `\xpatchbibdriver` provided by `xpatch` is useful here.